# How to display a lookup field on a custom list when using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, sharepoint-2013

I have a script that calls a custom list and displays information to the SharePoint page.  I'm able to get the information, but not able to display the Section attribute.  Section is an object.  Section is a Lookup to another custom list on my site.  Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    loadItems();    
});    

function loadItems() {    
          console.log("loadItems ...");
    var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;    
    var oDataUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Contacts')/items?$select=Title,Organization,Section/Title,Business_x0020_Phone,Created&$expand=Section";    
    $.ajax({    
        url: oDataUrl,    
        type: "GET",    
        dataType: "json",    
        headers: {    
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"    
        },    
        success: mySuccHandler,    
        error: myErrHandler    
    });    
}    

function mySuccHandler(data) {    
    try {    
          console.log("Success loading");

        $('#table_id').DataTable({    

            "aaData": data.d.results,    
            "aoColumns": [  
            {    
                "mData": "Title"    
            },   
            {    
                "mData": "Organization"    
            },   
            {    
                "mData": "Section"    
            },   
            {    
                "mData": "Business_x0020_Phone"    
            },  
            {    
                "mData": "Created"    
            }             
            ]    
        });    
    } catch (e) {    
        alert(e.message);    
    }    
}

function myErrHandler(data, errMessage) {    
    console.log("Error: " + errMessage);    
}
```

What should the syntax be for displaying the Section?

Comment: can you provide a example of the response in order to replicate your problem ? also if section is a sub object how do you want to display it ? is attribute a key name of some element from the Section object ?

Comment: I want to display the Title in the lookup table (the lookup value).  e.g. Data Collection & Support.  What currently displays is [object Object].  Are you asking what does the response look like from the call?    <entry>
<id>3a11302f-0d64-473e-aa88-ce30d657d7c7 </id>
<category term="SP.Data.SectionsListItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
<title />
<updated>2019-12-17T21:11:32Z </updated>
<author>
<name />
</author>
<content type="application/xml">
<m:properties>
<d:Title>Day-to-Day Operations</d:Title>
</m:properties>
</content>
</entry>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Objects, I need to use the following syntax:

```
{    
    "mDataProp": "Section.Title"    
}
```

Instead of

```
{    
    "mData": "Section"    
}
```